# Mocks or factories in unit tests for a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, model-view-controller, controller

I have a `DashboardController` with an `index` method that interacts with my `User` model along these lines:

```
def index
  user = User.first
  log_data = user.logs
  # more controller code here that uses the log_data
end
```

I'm writing controller specs for this `index` method. I have a FactoryGirl factory defined for my user model.  In the unit test for this, should I be mocking out the `user` here with an `instance_double` of some sort, or should I instead create a `User` object with FactoryGirl? Is there a convention/standard/tendency on how to test a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is no need to be mocking a user object - it only takes your specs further from the reality. You can happily set up your specs like so:

```
describe DashboardController, :type => :controller do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  describe "#index" do
    it "your test here" do
      ####
    end
  end

end
```

In another instance where you are accessing the `current_user` object you may seek to utilise the following however:

```
let(:user) { create :user }

before do
  allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```